# 'Self' in parent class method

Tags: php, class, inheritance, parent, self

See the following example (taken from a previous question):

```
    class ClassA {
         public static function test(){ self::getVar();       }
         public static function getVar(){ echo 'A'; }
    }        

    class ClassB extends ClassA {
         public static function getVar(){ echo 'B'; }
   }

ClassA::test(); // prints 'A'

ClassB::test(); // also prints 'A'
```

Is there a way such that when `B` calls `test()`, `self` will call `B`'s `getVar()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about is called [Late Static Binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and it's available since PHP 5.3. All you need to do is use the word `static` instead of `self`:

```
class ClassA {
    public static function test() { return static::getVar(); }
}
class ClassB  extends ClassA {
    public static function getVar() { return 'B'; }
}

echo ClassB::test(); // prints 'B'
```